# Using postfix, how to replace _sender_ address with a specific value, depending on the _destination_ address?

Tags: email, smtp, postfix

I have a peering SMTP server (say, example0.test) that is rejecting all mail that is not sent from a specific address. (Say, password@example.test).

In postfix, whenever it sees a mail sent to '.*@example0.test', I want it to throw away the original from: address, and replace it with 'password@example.test'.

How can I do this?

As a bonus, it would be nice to append the original from: address to the subject line.

Comment: Which SMTP server ?